# ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS The following resource(s) failed to create: [ECSService]

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Following this tutorial, I have created an ECS cluster. Then I created 2 Tasks. The tasks are active. Now I am trying to set up a Service with the same settings described in the linked article:

https://aws-solutions-library-samples.github.io/advertising-marketing/using-google-tag-manager-for-server-side-website-analytics-on-aws.html

However, the Services aren't being created. This is what I see in CloudFormation Stack logs:

**ECS-Console-V2-Service-PrimaryServerSideService-gtm-cluster-785cbbcd

ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS
The following resource(s) failed to create: [ECSService]. Rollback requested by user.**

**ECSService

CREATE_FAILED
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: d684e343-c07235555, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)**

When I check in Cloudwatch, the log groups are created for ECS but they are empty so far. What could be possible reasons?

Currently, when I create the Services, I don't see any option to select an IAM role. Is it changeable?

Comment: IAM roles are at the task level, not the service level. Also, the error is just saying that it failed to deploy so many times that the deployment circuit breaker has kicked in. You need to go to the task list, view all tasks so you can see the stopped ones, and then view the details of one of those stopped tasks to see why it is failing.

Comment: I checked the task definitions. there are only 2 and both of them are ACTIVE. how else do i debug? i don't see any other relevant logs except the stack (cloudformation) ones @MarkB

Comment: No, you need to look at the Tasks, not the Task Definitions. Go to the ECS Service, then inside there will be a "Tasks" Tab. Go into that tab, and change the dropdown to show all tasks. It should show the ones that have stopped recently in there. If you haven't deployed in a while it may be empty and you will need to deploy again, then look at the stopped tasks.

Comment: Got it: InternalError: failed to create container model: failed to normalize image reference "http://gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image". Launch a new task to retry. If I see the linked tutorial, this is the link they have provided. But I am not sure if I am supposed to get a similar link from somewhere in my GTM or if this is a standard link. I couldn't find a link on the GTM interface @MarkB

Comment: Can you post your task definition, or at least the exact `"image"` value you are using? It sounds like there is something invalid in the image specification you provided. See similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384815/ecs-internalerror-failed-to-normalize-image-reference